# subprocess checkout error only when service is not started

Tags: python

I am trying to check the status of the apache service thru a simple subprocess call however the script keeps returning a "non-zero exit status 3" error. When the apache service is running, I get the results that I'm looking for. The error only occurs when the apache service is not running. I have included the simple script below.

What would you guys recommend I do for troubleshooting to try to figure this out? Thanks!

```
import subprocess
from shlex import split

subprocess.check_output(split("services apache2 status"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subprocess works just fine in your case:
note that `check_output` function will first check the command exit code. If the exit code is not 0, it will raise the CalledProcessError[Refer here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

For your case, if the apache2 is not running, the exit code of `service apache2 status` will just give the exit code 3.

You can check the exit code of a command in terminal just put "`echo $?`" follow that command.

For example:
If the apache2 is not running, type "service apache2 status" in the terminal and execute the command, then type "echo $?", you will get the exit code 3.

If you just want to get the output of command "service apache2 status", I suggest that you add the "`shell = True`" args, refer here: [link doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

e.g.

> subprocess.check_output(split("services apache2 status"), shell =
>   True)

But be careful with this args, only use it if you just want to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior of `subprocess.check_output`. If the process called does not return an exit code of 0, it will raise an `CalledProcessError` exception.

If you want your script to continue running you need to handle the exception, for example:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output(split("services apache2 status"))
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print("subprocess failed with return code {}".format(e.returncode))
```